# Error when navigating trough multiple pages with common navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a project where the top bar and navigation menu is the same in every page. I was able to create this menu and include it with jQuery as I want to work in the client side. The issue that I have is with the navigation through the directories. All of the html files are in a subfolder named "subpages" and the index file and the header file are located in the root directory.

It loads fine and it navigates well from home to any page, but I can't make it work to go back to the main page or another one. I guess I am not doing it fine. What I did to partially solve the problem is to have two different header files, one of them is in the main directory and the other one is within that subpages folder, so I have to edit both header files when I make changes.

I leave the code from my main header.

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "280px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
}

var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     this.classList.toggle("active");
     var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
     if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
         dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
     } else {
         dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
     }
 });
}
```

```css
body,html{
 padding:0;margin:0;
 background-color:#F4F4F4;
}

#wrapper-header{
 color:white;
    font-size: 28px;
 float:left;
 width:105%;
 height:65px;
 background-color:#2E2D30;
}

#main-header{
 position:relative;
 width:1200px;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-580px;
 height:auto;
}

.page-title{
 position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    left: 25%;
    top: 45%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.sidepanel {
 height: 100%;
 width: 0;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #111;
 font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding-top: 60px;
 transition: 0.5s; 
  }
  
  .sidepanel a, .dropdown-btn {
 padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 25px;
 color: #818181;
 display: block;
 border: none;
    background: none;
 transition: 0.3s;
 outline: none;
 font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  }
  
  .sidepanel a:hover, .dropdown-btn:hover {
 color: #f1f1f1;
  }
  
  .sidepanel .closebtn {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 25px;
 font-size: 36px;
 margin-left: 50px;
  }
  
  .openbtn {
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #2E2D30;
 color: white;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 border: none;
 transform: scale(1.6);
  }
  
  .openbtn:hover {
 background-color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
  }

.dropdown-container {
 display: none;
 background-color: #262626;
 padding-left: 8px;
 font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  }
  
  .fa-caret-down {
 margin-left: 18px;
 float: right;
 padding-right: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper-header">
 <div id="main-header" class="object">
  <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</button>
  <div class="page-title">PAGE TITLE</div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- NAVBAR -->

<div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
 <a href="index.html">Recientes</a>
 <button class="dropdown-btn">Para empezar
     <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
 <div class="dropdown-container">
  <a href="subpages/nivel1_5.html">Nivel 1-5</a>
     <a href="subpages/nivel6_10">Nivel 6-10</a>
  <a href="subpages/nivel11_15">Nivel 11-15</a>
 </div>
 <a href="subpages_arreglos">Arreglos</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You navigate to relative `subpages/nivel1_5.html` instead of absolute paths `/subpages/nivel1_5.html`, that means that when you navigate to `www.domain.com/subpages/nivel1_5.html` the next time you'll try to navigate it will try to go to `www.domain.com/subpages/nivel1_5.html/subpages/nivel6_10` you have to add a `/` in front of your urls.

Comment: I have tried and I am doing something wrong. I added / in front of the urls in a way that I have now: /index.html to go to the main file and /subpages/arreglos to go to a subdirectory. When I navigate from home to "arreglos" it goes just fine, but when I try to come back to the index.html it looks for the file inside the address "/subpages/index.html" but in the file I wrote "/index.html". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you loading the pages with Ajax?

Comment: Yes. I am loading both the header and pages with the lines: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.min.js"></script>